# ASP.NET Identity IUserEmailStore error in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, identity, usermanager

I am trying to send a confirmation email when a user registers together with the generated Token. Token is OK. But when sending email,I am getting this error:

```
System.NotSupportedException: Store does not implement IUserEmailStore<TUser>.
```

And my code inside AccountController in the Register method looks like this: It is the SendEmailAsync() method which is causing the error:

```
if (result.Succeeded)
{
    var code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
    var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
    await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking this link: <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">link</a>");
    ViewBag.Link = callbackUrl;
    return View("DisplayEmail");
}
```

In my IdentityConfig.cs file, I have a class:

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
        public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store)
            : base(store)
        {
        }
}
```

Also inside my IdentityConfig.cs file, I have another class:

```
public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
    {
        public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
        {
            // Plug in your email service here to send an email.
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
            return client.SendMailAsync(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TranscriptEmailAddr"],
                                        message.Destination,
                                        message.Subject,
                                        message.Body);                       
        }
    }
```

Please assist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just figured out that I had `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework` `v1.0.0` installed but I needed `v2.x`. I installed it through the Package Manager console by entering:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework -Version 2.2.1
```

In this later version, `UserStore` implements `IUserEmailStore` which has the new email methods.

Answer (score 3):

In your model, or somewhere in your code you must have a UserStore class (unless you use a framework like `EntityFrameworkIdentity`).

Try to find it by searching the entire solution for `UserStore` and you'll see that you have to implement this interface on it.

like:

```
public class UserStore : IUserStore<UserIdentity>, IUserPasswordStore<UserIdentity>, IUserEmailStore<UserIdentity>{
}
```

Comment: Hi @Henrique. Yes, I am using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework so I understand I do not have to explicitly implement the IUserStore. What is causing more worry for me is that I have downloaded a sample project by installing in Package Manager like this: PM > Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples -Pre. That project is working fine and is able to send email but my project is not working.